# LaravelLocalization failing to translate routes of nwidart laravel modules

Tags: php, module, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I can't figure out why LaravelLocalization cannot translate the routes which I'm declaring in routes.php (Modules/ModuleName/Http/routes.php) file of a module which I create with nwidart laravel-modules package for laravel, 'localize' (\Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class) middleware is also present in the app's Kernel.php and in the route group as stated in [here](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#middleware). The route is not translated and appears as /en/booking::all.companies.index instead of /en/companies (or /ru/kompanii):

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'localize', 'optimizeImages'],
    'namespace' => 'Modules\Booking\Http\Controllers',
],
function() {
    Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('booking::all.companies.index'), 'CompanyController@index')->name('booking.companies.index');
});
```

but when module namespace prefix "booking::" is removed from translation string (LaravelLocalization::transRoute('all.companies.index') instead of LaravelLocalization::transRoute('booking::all.companies.index')) it CAN translate the route.

Please help me to resolve the issue, thanks.

(My installation if it helps: Laravel Framework 5.5.43, "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.3", "nwidart/laravel-modules": "2.7". No other localization package is installed besides mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: You have found any Solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm placing routes translations in the standard laravel resources/lang directory. Namespaced route names (e.g.: "booking::", placed for example in Modules/Booking/Resources/lang directory) are not being translated correctly by mcamara/laravel-localization package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I didn't find the solution online. Here's how I solved the problem:

In  `Modules\[MyModule]\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
/**
 * Register translations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerTranslations()
{
    $module_path = 'MyModule';
    $module_slug = 'my-module';

    $langPath = resource_path('lang/modules/'.$module_slug);

    if (is_dir($langPath)) {
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom($langPath, $module_slug);
    } else {
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(module_path(module_path, 'Resources/lang'),$module_slug);
    }
}

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->registerTranslations();
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that it's working, thanks @apalette. I've accepted the answer.